# Position Div on top of/over table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div dropdown menu above a table that is positioned absolute above a table and, when it is opened (using JQuery to set the height from 0 to its height with a transition), it bleeds down over the table. However, even though it's absolute positioned and I've set the `z-index` to a high value, the contents of the table still overlap (just the `<td>`). However, the div does go over the `<th>`, which I dont understand and would appreciate for someone to explain to me why that is so. Additionally, the checkboxes in the div are not clickable.

So, my question is how can I position the div over the entire table?

My simplified code is something like this:

```
<div class="dropdown>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th> <!-- Why is this overlapped by .dropdown -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data</td> <!-- Yet this isn't -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example. Without your CSS how would we begin to help you? Please include more HTML, your jQuery and CSS. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: no simplified code is needed, otherwise no one will explain anything useful to you. please give more information - html, css, jquery

Comment: I agree. I'm very much intrigued, but without a live code snippet reproducing the problem I can't begin to solve this.

Comment: My mistake, I had the <td> set to position relative, removing that fixed it.

Comment: Make an answer for it, otherwise the question remains unanswered forever

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone troubleshooting a problem like this, my fix was my `<td>` were set to `position: relative`, deleting that allowed me to have overflow just fine.